# Vuetify3 components in Storybook decorators with vue3 and vite

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vite

I' have an app with storybook, vue3, vite and vuetify3 and typescript in which I'm unable to use any of the vuetify components inside of decorators. I'm getting `[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: v-app`

The components in my stories, which internally use vuetify3 components load and render without any issues.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this is happening, or an URL to a repo with a working cofinguration?

This is my setup

```js
//main.js
const path = require('path')
const vuetify = require('@vuetify/vite-plugin')

module.exports = {
  stories: [
    '../src/**/*.stories.mdx',
    '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
  ],
  core: { builder: "@storybook/builder-vite" },
  viteFinal: (config) => {
    config.resolve.alias['~storybook'] = path.resolve(__dirname)
    config.resolve.alias['@'] = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src')
    config.plugins = [
        ...config.plugins,
      vuetify({
        autoImport: true,
      })
    ]
    return config
  },
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
  ]
}
```

```js
//preview.js
import { app } from '@storybook/vue3'
import vuetify from '../src/plugins/vuetify'

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
}

export const decorators = [story => ({
  components: { story },
  template: '<v-app><story /></v-app>',
})]

app.use(vuetify)
```

```json
//package.json
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-vue": "^1.0.1",
    "vue": "^3.2.25",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.15",
    "vuetify": "^3.0.0-beta.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.10",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/builder-vite": "^0.1.33",
    "@storybook/vue3": "^6.4.22",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.3.1",
    "@vuetify/vite-plugin": "^1.0.0-alpha.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "sass": "^1.38.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "vite": "^2.9.7",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.4.8",
    "vue-loader": "^16.8.3",
    "vue-tsc": "^0.34.7",
    "vuetify-loader": "^2.0.0-alpha.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: One issue with Storybook is that the main engine loads via one builder (webpack) whereas your library loads into an iframe via another (here, Vite).

I suspect that the issue is caused by your global decorator being compiled by webpack, which doesn't have a vuetify-loader attached.

Does it work if you move the decorator into your `component.stories.js` file?

Comment: also npm suggest that you need to use 'vite-plugin-vuetify' instead of deprecated '@vuetify/vite-plugin'

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same problem.
My issue was that in `../src/plugins/vuetify` file I didnt use components and directives inside createVuetify..

```
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'
export default createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
})
```

Comment: It was not obvious at all (even in their official examples)... thanks for sharing!